# Cannot Disable Hyperlink Warning Excel 2019

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, hyperlink

I linked some cell text to .mp4 files on my computer. Every time I click the link, I get the following warning that I don't want to see:

[image]

I tried adding this registry 32-bit dword:

[image]
but that didn't fix it even after restarting the computer.
I tried adding the containing folder to my "trusted locations" in the "Trust Center", but that didn't work either.

How am I supposed to make this thing go away? I'm on Office Professional Plus 2019 and Excel 1807 (build 10325.20082).

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if this article is helpful:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/troubleshoot/administration/enable-disable-hyperlink-warning

Comment: Unfortunately the solutions presented in that article did not work for me.